# Is there a way to import external scripts in Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, webview, flutterwebviewplugin

I'm trying to load an external script into Flutter WebView, but it doesn't seem to work. It's about tinyMCE in particular. So the intention is to open a rich text editor in an AlertDialog with WebView inside. Is that possible?

The following is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.2.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#test',
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
      'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
      'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
    'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
    'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
    'removeformat | help',
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And that's my widget:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class RichTextEditor extends StatefulWidget {
  final String html;

  const RichTextEditor({
    this.html: '',
  });

  @override
  RichTextEditorState createState() => RichTextEditorState();
}

class RichTextEditorState extends State<RichTextEditor> {
  WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String source = Uri.dataFromString(
      widget.html,
      mimeType: 'text/html',
      encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    ).toString();

    return Container(
      child: Material(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                ),
              ],
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: WebView(
                initialUrl: source,
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
                  _webViewController = controller;
                  _webViewController.loadUrl(source);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

I get the following logs in the console:

```
D/cr_Ime  (30910): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:30] Constructor
W/cr_AwContents(30910): onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
D/cr_Ime  (30910): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: false
I/cr_Ime  (30910): ImeThread is not enabled.
D/EGL_emulation(30910): eglMakeCurrent: 0x8a0f4ca0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x8976d190)
W/cr_BindingManager(30910): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 30910
D/cr_Ime  (30910): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
D/cr_Ime  (30910): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
D/EGL_emulation(30910): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb1e05240: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb1e03310)
W/cr_BindingManager(30910): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 30910
D/cr_Ime  (30910): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:59] isActive: true
D/cr_Ime  (30910): [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:68] hideSoftInputFromWindow
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I/art     (30910): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 12(424B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 22MB/22MB, paused 10.801ms total 19.097ms
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
I/chromium(30910): [INFO:CONSOLE(9)] "Failed to initialize the editor as the document is not in standards mode. TinyMCE requires standards mode.", source: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.2.1/tinymce.min.js (9)
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
W/art     (30910): Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make `TinyMCE` work, you need to add also `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the start of your HTML (see https://community.tiny.cloud/communityQuestion?id=9064N000000MvpyQAC).

You can also try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) if it doesn't work with `webview_flutter`.
It's a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

Here is an example using `initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData()` attribute to inject an initial HTML string inside the WebView:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialData: InAppWebViewInitialData(data: """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/5.2.1/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
<script>
  tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea#test',
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
      'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
      'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
      'insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | ' +
    'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter ' +
    'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | ' +
    'removeformat | help',
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
"""),
                    initialHeaders: {},
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                      crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      ),
                      android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                        builtInZoomControls: true
                      )
                    ),
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      webView = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    }
                  ))
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am trying to use your solution in Flutter Web, but using the code above I get the following errors:
1) the second parameter of onLoadStart and onLoadStop function is Uri and not String
2) in the browser, I get "targetPlatform.windows is not yet supported by the flutter_inappwebview plugin"

Comment: Ciao Francesco, as you can see, this question is old and, in the meantime, the plugin evolved. This example works with the old version 4.0.0+4.
For the first error: you can just remove the type from the argument or change it to `Uri` (URLs, in general, have now `Uri` type in new version 5!).
For the second error: yes, this plugin supports only Android and iOS at the moment. I will add also support for MacOS, Linux and Windows, but it will take a lot of time